# JQuery .ajax request does not hit the server

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am making an ajax request using JQuery that looks like this:

`var data = createXMLdata();
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/foo/bar',
    type: "PUT",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/text",
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("Error: " + status);
    },
    success: function() {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});`

When the code executes, I get the success alert, but the service is never executed on the server!

Here's some more data:

- If I make the same request using a separate [REST client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/), the service is executed correctly
- If I shut down the server (nothing is running) so that hitting that URL gives me a 404, I still get a success message.
- I have tried replacing the data with "foo". This works from the REST client, but gives the same result from the code.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the page you're running this in also served from port 8080?

Comment: No it is not. I am using Aptana, so while developing, the pages run off of its built-in in-memory web server on port 8000.

Comment: Aha! I deployed the code to tomcat (where my RESTful services are deployed) and the service got called correctly. It must have been a cross-site scripting issue.  Still not sure why JQuery was calling the success callback in this case.

Nick, if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: What web server are you running? I know IIS doesn't support anything but GET and POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick Craver made a comment on my question:

> Is the page you're running this in served from port 8080?

It turns out this led to me solving the problem.  When both the app and the service were hosted on the same server (and port), the problem went away.

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question) suggests that if I comment answers the question, and the commenter does not re-post as an answer, I am to post my own answer and accept it.  Nick, if you return to post this as an answer, I will accept it over my own.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation about `.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)'s `type` attribute says:

> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as `PUT` and `DELETE`, can also be used here, but **they are not supported by all browsers**.

So probably your browser does not support `PUT` and the data is sent via `POST` instead (and therefore not recognized by your service).
Use Firebug or similar to find out which method is used.

---

One idea to make it working:

Send the data using `POST` but add an additional field e.g. `__http_method=PUT`. On the server side, your service has to recognize this and perform the `PUT` functionality.

This might be not the nicest solution but it is also used by other frameworks I have encountered (e.g. symfony for PHP).

Comment: I have tried in Firefox, Chrome, and IE. Firefox and Chrome behave as described, IE gives me an "Access is denied" error (I figured I would get that until I was running the app off of 8080).

Do you think that PUT is the problem?  If PUT was not supported, shouldn't I get an error rather than a success message?

Comment: Hmm -- I tried using POST rather than PUT and I see the same behavior. I must be calling this incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

PUT isn't supported by all browsers